# Issue with JNI when run makefile --add-stdcall-alias

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am facing a problem with JNI when I run the makefile with the target all

This is my problem:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project TestTapeJNI ****
make all 
javah -classpath ../bin TestTape
gcc -I"/home/tanio/DevelopmentEnvironment/jdk1.7.0_51/include"I"/home/tanio/DevelopmentEnvironment/jdk1.7.0_51/include/linux" -c TestTape.c -o TestTape.o
gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o Tape.dll TestTape.o 
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--add-stdcall-alias' 
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Tape.dll] Error 1
```

Do you know what the problem is?

**EDIT**

If I try to cancell it from the makefile this problem is triggered

```
make all 
javah -classpath ../bin TestTape
gcc -Wl, -shared -o Tape.dll TestTape.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Tape.dll] Error 1
```

**MAKEFILE**

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : Tape.dll

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
Tape.dll : TestTape.o
    gcc -Wl, -shared -o $@ $<

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
TestTape.o : TestTape.c TestTape.h
    gcc -I"/home/tanio/DevelopmentEnvironment/jdk1.7.0_51/include"  -I"/home/tanio/DevelopmentEnvironment/jdk1.7.0_51/include/linux" -c $< -o $@

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
TestTape.h : TestTape.class
    javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
    rm TestTape.h TestTape.o Tape.dll
```

Comment: I managed to run the makefile correctly without it but the program still cannot find my library. What does that option do?

Comment: In the make I see a reference to a windows dll (Tape.dll) and an include of a Linux directory (.../include/Linux).  Is this mix intentional? And your "clean" also has a mix of Linux (TestTape.o) and windows (Tape.dll).  and...When does PulpFiction Part2 hit the street?

Answer (score 1):

As per this link http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/ld_4.html

So a working solution is just remove it (..std..alisa..) and your gcc command now becomes:

```
gcc -Wl -shared -o Tape.dll TestTape.o
```